# Read from mongodb without lock

Tags: mongodb

We're using MongoDB 2.2.0 at work. The DB contains about 51GB of data (at the moment) and I'd like to do some analytics on the user data that we've collected so far. Problem is, it's the live machine and we can't afford another slave at the moment. I know MongoDB has a read lock which may affect any writes that happen especially with complex queries. Is there a way to tell MongoDB to treat my (particular) query with the lowest priority?

Comment: Writes can effect reads but but a read is so fast and the dynamics of it are such that there is a 1/1,000,000 chance of a read effecting a write opreation. More like the usage of JS locks and bad write operations will result in problems in queries. As to telling MongoDB about priorities, I do not believe there is a method yet

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In MongoDB reads and writes do affect each other.  Read locks are shared, but read locks block write locks from being acquired and of course no other reads or writes are happening while a write lock is held.  MongoDB operations yield periodically to keep other threads waiting for locks from starving.  You can read more about the details of that [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/faq/concurrency/#does-a-read-or-write-operation-ever-yield-the-lock).

What does that mean for your use case?  Because there is no way to tell MongoDB to access the data without a read lock, nor is there a way to prioritize the requests (at least not yet) whether the reads significantly affect the performance of your writes depends on how much "headroom" you have available while write activity is going on.

One suggestion I can make is when figuring out how to run analytics, rather than scanning the entire data set (i.e. doing an aggregation query over all historical data) try running smaller aggregation queries on short time slices.  This will accomplish two things:

1. reads jobs will be shorter lived and therefore will finish quicker, this will give you a chance to assess what impact the queries have on your "live" performance.
2. you won't be pulling all old data into RAM at once - by spacing out these analytical queries over time you will minimize the impact it will have on current write performance.

Depending on what it is you can't afford about getting another server - you might consider getting a short lived AWS instance which may be not very powerful but would be available to run a long analytical query against a copy of your data set.   Just be careful when making it a copy of your data - doing a full sync off of the production system will place a heavy load on it (more effective way would be to use a recent backup/file snapshot to resume from).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think the slicing part is a great idea. I'll give that a shot. We have indexes on the _id field, what is the best way to slice based on that? I'm thinking writing a `.js` file which will accept parameters for slicing and then triggering that through a shell script or something. Correct me if I'm wrong, but I'm guessing running a javascript file in mongo will create a lock for the entire duration of the script, hence the shell script which calls the javascript. This way I can run a shell script which calls mongo 100 times, each time processing 1% of the data

Comment: running a javascript file won't create any lock (it just invokes the shell which doesn't take locks).  I assume the js file will contain the actual query you want to run (parameterized for ranges?)  _id fields leading four bytes represent the datetime of creation of ObjectId value so any sequential partitioning would work.

Answer (score 2):

Such operations are best left for slaves of a replica set. For one thing, read locks can be shared to allow many reads at once, but write locks will block reads. And, while you can't prioritize queries, mongodb yields long running read/write queries. [Their concurrency docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/faq/concurrency/#does-a-read-or-write-operation-ever-yield-the-lock) should help

If you can't afford another server, you can setup a slave on the same machine, provided you have some spare RAM/Disk headroom, and you use the slave lightly/occasionally. You must be careful though, your disk I/O will increase significantly.

Comment: While most of your observation is correct, read locks *do* block writes - a write lock cannot be acquired if a read lock exists (otherwise read couldn't be guaranteed to be consistent!)

Comment: @AsyaKamsky he says "read locks don't block writes" but they do don't they? I mean how can you judge, as you said, the consistency of a read. I am unsure if it was so good to direct me to this answer

Comment: @Adil - Thanks for your answer. It's an interesting idea to setup a slave on the same machine but I think that won't give me the necessary power to run the queries I'm looking for

Comment: Does this mean that a process can run a query on a secondary while another process simultaneously writes to the same database in the primary?